# How to know whether the ewa_lanczossharp rendering filter is working on mpv?

Tags: video, gpu, intel-graphics, mpv

For rendering video with a GPU, the [mpv documentation](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#video-output-drivers) states,

> `wa_lanczossharp`
>
> A slightly sharpened version of ewa_lanczos,
> preconfigured to use an ideal radius and parameter. If your hardware
> can run it, this is probably what you should use by default.

I've tried this option and the video plays. But when I check the usage of my Intel GPU via `intel_gpu_top`, I notice that the usage actually *drops* from around 6% (when using the default `spline36` filter on `gpu-hq`) to around 2%.

My intuition tells me if a filter produces better quality, then it should make *more* use of the GPU. But the opposite seems to be happening.

So, if the video plays and my system reports *some* GPU usage while rendering, is my system actually using the `ewa_lanczossharp` filter correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer lies in what's reported on the terminal, specifically the output of **audio/video sync** and **dropped frames**.

Per the man page:

> The audio/video sync as A-V:  0.000. This is the difference between
> audio and video time. Normally it should be 0 or close to 0. If it's
> growing, it might indicate a playback problem. (avsync property.)

and,

> Dropped frames, e.g. Dropped: 4. Shows up only if the count is not 0.
> Can grow if the video framerate is higher than that of the display, or
> if video rendering is too slow. May also be incremented on "hiccups"
> and when the video frame couldn't be  displayed  on  time.
> (frame-drop-count property.)   If  the  decoder  drops frames, the
> number of decoder-dropped frames is appended to the display as well,
> e.g.: Dropped: 4/34. This happens only if decoder frame dropping is
> enabled with the --framedrop options.  (decoder-frame-drop-count
> property.)

Answer (score 0):

On mpv.net I can right-click -> View -> Advanced -> Show Properties then in the input dialog I can select 'scale', 'cscale' or 'dscale' and it will report the current setting in the console. To see the console you must either launch it from a terminal window or turn the console on with `.

On mpv without a GUI overlay I am not sure if you can do this. And yes, GPU usage is still small even with these supposedly expensive options turned on. That makes me fear they are not working, but I think mpv is just incredibly efficient. This is unlike madVR which will use a ton of GPU and then choke if you aren't careful.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer).